# Adding data to createTableViewRow() in appcelerator

Tags: javascript, date, titanium, appcelerator

How can i add custom data to a TableViewRow?

I'm using createTableViewRow() to setup a TableRow which I'm then added labels and images to it, then finally putting all these TableRows in a TableView. This works fine, but the rows need to have a "date" attribute attached to them, as I'm sorted these rows by dates before they are shown in the TableView.

How would i add a "date" to these TableRows? All these are unixtimestamps.

Comment: Would it be possible to just use table_row.date = date;? If so, when i put each row in an array (called data), how would i retreive this date from the table_row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({height:50, _date_var: date});
```

it can just be attached as a property and retrieved like this

```
row._date_var
```

Answer (score 0):

As an add-on to Aaron's answer, if you want to retrieve the date in a click event on the row, you can access it with

`e.row._date_var`

as in

```
tableview.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({
      title:'DB Test', 
      message:'date: ' +  e.row._date_var
    }).show();
});
```

This should probably be a comment to Aaron's answer if someone with reputation wants to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Watch out with adding custom variables to views and other Ti objects. If your variable is going to hold something more complex than a string or a number (e.g. an object, particularly a complex object), then it is possible that iOS will crash at some point.

Check out this thread for more details.

https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/122924/how-to-fix-strange-javascript-behaviour-and-crashes-on-ios